Javascript remove duplicate keys from array
I have 6 input fields I am capturing user inputs and placing into a new array to filter out a table. I am using keyup on the inputs and pushing the inputs into the query array. However, every new keyup pushes the current input string into the array, creating multiple copies of each key with its value. I need to sort all duplicate keys leaving the last indexed version of that key.
var operatorFilter = document.querySelector("#operatorFilters");
    operatorFilter.innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="idFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "id")' placeholder="Operator ID"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="operatorFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "operatorName")' placeholder="Operator Name"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="facilityFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "facility")' placeholder="Facility"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="pieceCountFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "piece")' placeholder="Piece Count"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="jobCountFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "job")' placeholder="Job Count"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="dateFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "date")' placeholder="Date Filter"></input>`

var query = []

function idFilter(userInput, inputID){
    
    var inputHolder = [] 
    
    if(inputID == "id"){
        inputHolder = ({operatorID:userInput.value})
    }
    else if(inputID == "operatorName"){
        inputHolder = ({operatorFirst:userInput.value}, {operatorLast:userInput.value})
    }
    else if(inputID == "facility"){
        inputHolder = ({facility:userInput.value})
    }
    else if(inputID == "piece"){
        inputHolder = ({pieceCount:userInput.value})
    }
    else if(inputID == "job"){
        inputHolder = ({jobCount:userInput.value})
    }
    else if(inputID == "date"){
        inputHolder = ({date:userInput.value})
    }

    console.log(inputHolder)
    query.push(inputHolder)

    console.log(query)
}

//Example

//console logged output

0: {operatorID: '3'}
1: {operatorID: '36'}
2: {operatorID: '368'}
3: {operatorID: '3689'}
4: {operatorLast: 'B'}
5: {operatorLast: 'B'}
6: {operatorLast: 'Bo'}
7: {operatorLast: 'Bob'}
8: {operatorLast: 'Bob '}
9: {operatorLast: 'Bob S'}
10: {operatorLast: 'Bob S'}
11: {operatorLast: 'Bob Smi'}
12: {operatorLast: 'Bob Smi'}
13: {operatorLast: 'Bob Smit'}
14: {operatorLast: 'Bob Smith'}
15: {date: '08'}
16: {date: '08/'}
17: {date: '08/2'}
18: {date: '08/25'}
19: {date: '08/25/'}
20: {date: '08/25/2'}
21: {date: '08/25/20'}
22: {date: '08/25/202'}
23: {date: '08/25/2024'}

I need to remove the duplicates of keys leaving the last input for each input field
I found what I thought would be a solution and set it up within another test trigger
function testFilter(){
    query = query.filter((value, index, self) =>
        index === self.findIndex((t) => (
            t.place === value.place && t.name === value.name
        ))
    )
    console.log(query)
}

//Expected Result
   
0: {operatorID: '3689'}
1: {operatorLast: 'Bob Smith'}
2: {date: '08/25/2024'}

//Actual result
0: {operatorID: '3'}


do you have the html part as well and a small data set? why not make a working snippet with <>?

btw, why not use the same name doe each filter and not differetn ones like for piece/pieceCount.

t.place === value.place && t.name === value.name: where are the place and name properties? I can't see them anywhere. If they're not defined, the condition is just undefined === undefined && undefined === undefined, which resolves to true for every element, so the findIndex method would always return 0, so your filter method would be equivalent to filter((_, index) => index === 0), which, of course, would return the result you see on the console.

@user27425627
Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't even notice that. Completely looked past that.

@qqq
You are right, I need to update those to keep it standardized.
Thank you for comments and will review

Thank you all for the comments and help. This problem has been resolved.

If you like to keep different names, you could take an object and get the wanted objects.


var operatorFilter = document.querySelector("#operatorFilters");
operatorFilter.innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="idFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "id")' placeholder="Operator ID"></input>
    <input type="text" id="operatorFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "operatorName")' placeholder="Operator Name"></input>
    <input type="text" id="facilityFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "facility")' placeholder="Facility"></input>
    <input type="text" id="pieceCountFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "piece")' placeholder="Piece Count"></input>
    <input type="text" id="jobCountFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "job")' placeholder="Job Count"></input>
    <input type="text" id="dateFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "date")' placeholder="Date Filter"></input>`
    
const query = {};

function idFilter(userInput, inputID) {
    const
        data = {
            id: { operatorID: userInput.value },
            operatorName: [{ operatorFirst: userInput.value }, { operatorLast: userInput.value }],
            facility: { facility: userInput.value },
            piece: { pieceCount: userInput.value },
            job: { jobCount: userInput.value },
            date: { date: userInput.value }
        };
    if (userInput.value === '') delete query[inputID];
    else query[inputID] = data[inputID];
    
    console.log(Object.values(query).flat());
}
<div id="operatorFilters"></div>




Thank you for the help with this. It has solved my dilemma.

Why do you need copies of input?
The best way is without copies or array, just an object with keys
Like:
var operatorFilter = document.querySelector("#operatorFilters");
operatorFilter.innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="idFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "operatorID")' placeholder="Operator ID"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="operatorFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "operatorFirst")' placeholder="Operator Name"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="facilityFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "facility")' placeholder="Facility"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="pieceCountFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "pieceCount")' placeholder="Piece Count"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="jobCountFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "jobCount")' placeholder="Job Count"></input>
                                <input type="text" id="dateFilter" onkeyup='idFilter(this, "date")' placeholder="Date Filter"></input>`

Note: i change "inputID" to be more direct
const query = {}

function idFilter(userInput, inputID) {
    const  value = userInput.value
    query[inputID] = value
    console.log(query)
}

